# Spring 3.0 Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/lang/NoAspectBoundException

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm having an error when trying to compile my Spring application. When I compile I get the following error:

```
Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/lang/NoAspectBoundException. Please see server.log for more details.
at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.devmodules.api.Deployment.deploy(Deployment.java:210)
at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.ant.Deploy.execute(Deploy.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor176.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:284)
at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:539)
at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
```

It worked fine before I modified the dispatcher-servlet.xml file. By attempting to add context.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:spring-configured/>
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="connect.controller"/>


<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

<!--
Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, but
for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, so we must
define an explicit mapping for it.
-->
<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
            <prop key="main.htm">mainViewController</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />

<!--
The index controller.
-->
<bean name="indexController"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
      p:viewName="index" />
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you deploying all the required libraries? Looks like you're missing a dependency (or a transitive dependency).

Comment: I think so. I'm using netbeans so it automatically builds the Spring skeleton.

Comment: But you've added dependencies; unless you're using Maven, I'm not convinced it would automatically add the required libraries. What libraries are you deploying?

Comment: I'm not using Maven. In the libraries section it does say it has the Spring Context 3.0.2 lib

Comment: What about the aspectj/aopalliance jars? This is why Maven/Ivy/etc. are valuable :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add the AspectJ jars.

At least [aspectjrt-1.x.x.jar](http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/org.aspectj.lang.NoAspectBoundException) is missing

Answer (score 0):

download http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/aspectjrt/aspectjrt.jar.zip
and unzip and add jar to your project